# How can I find applications written in a specific language?

Tags: silverlight, search, open-source

I'd like to find applications written, for example, on the Microsoft Silverlight platform. However, popular search engines such as the one integrated into SourceForge only list the root language, such as C#, and say little about XAML or Silverlight.

Does such a directory exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one that I know of is the Gallery at http://www.silverlight.net, but that is a listing of websites/projects done in Silverlight, but not open source (although some of them may be).

A search on http://www.codeplex.com for Silverlight does come up with a bunch of things though, it all depends on what you are looking for.